# How to implement entry point resolver endpoint? Example would be better

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I want to use entry point resolver in my project. But I don't know how to implement in the XML file. Please help me with examples of different entry point resolver.

Comment: You should be more descriptive with the question and mention the Mule context not only in the tags. All I can suggest is that you take a look at this post in MuleSoft's blog: http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/newbie/mule-school-invoking-component-methods-using-entry-point-resolvers/.

Answer (score 0):

There are different type of entry-point-resolver in Mule like *Reflection Entry, Point Resolver, Annotated Entry Point Resolver, Array entry point resolver* etc used in different ways.
EntryPoint Resolver are used to determine the entry point on a component or a Java Class after a message has been received.
You can go through the docs here to understand more and will help you to implement:-
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/entry-point-resolver-configuration-reference
and
http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/newbie/mule-school-invoking-component-methods-using-entry-point-resolvers/